# Android Asynchronous http for network call issue with 4.4,4.2

Tags: android, asynchronous, network-programming, loopj

android-async-http An Asynchronous HTTP Library for Android https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http

I am using asynchronous http for network calls. Lollipop and above Lollipop it's working perfectly. But below this version my code gives below error.

```
com.example.administrator.login E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams$1', referenced from method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.<init>
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8577 (Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams$1;) in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity', referenced from method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.createFormEntity
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9001 (Lcz/msebera/android/httpclient/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity;) in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 34133 (log) in Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient;
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.loopj.android.http.JsonStreamerEntity', referenced from method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.createJsonStreamerEntity
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8574 (Lcom/loopj/android/http/JsonStreamerEntity;) in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.loopj.android.http.SimpleMultipartEntity', referenced from method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8582 (Lcom/loopj/android/http/SimpleMultipartEntity;) in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'cz.msebera.android.httpclient.message.BasicNameValuePair', referenced from method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.getParamsList
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9302 (Lcz/msebera/android/httpclient/message/BasicNameValuePair;) in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x00f1
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: Could not find method cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format, referenced from method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.getParamString
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 61456: Lcz/msebera/android/httpclient/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils;.format (Ljava/util/List;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
05-29 04:04:11.388 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0006
05-29 04:04:11.392 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'cz.msebera.android.httpclient.message.BasicNameValuePair', referenced from method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.getParamsList
05-29 04:04:11.392 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9302 (Lcz/msebera/android/httpclient/message/BasicNameValuePair;) in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;
05-29 04:04:11.392 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x001b
05-29 04:04:11.392 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams$FileWrapper', referenced from method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.put
05-29 04:04:11.392 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8578 (Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams$FileWrapper;) in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;
05-29 04:04:11.392 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0012
05-29 04:04:11.392 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams$StreamWrapper.newInstance, referenced from method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.put
05-29 04:04:11.396 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 59098: Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams$StreamWrapper;.newInstance (Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams$StreamWrapper;
05-29 04:04:11.396 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0006
05-29 04:04:11.396 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams$FileWrapper', referenced from method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.put
05-29 04:04:11.396 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8578 (Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams$FileWrapper;) in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;
05-29 04:04:11.396 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x001b
05-29 04:04:11.396 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 34133 (log) in Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient;
05-29 04:04:11.396 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0005
05-29 04:04:11.396 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'cz.msebera.android.httpclient.message.BasicNameValuePair', referenced from method com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.toString
05-29 04:04:11.396 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 9302 (Lcz/msebera/android/httpclient/message/BasicNameValuePair;) in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;
05-29 04:04:11.396 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0106
05-29 04:04:11.400 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xe6d8 at 0x02 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.<init>
05-29 04:04:11.400 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xef74 at 0x08 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createFormEntity
05-29 04:04:11.400 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xe6d1 at 0x15 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createJsonStreamerEntity
05-29 04:04:11.400 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856e at 0xa2 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createJsonStreamerEntity
05-29 04:04:11.400 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856e at 0xac in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createJsonStreamerEntity
05-29 04:04:11.400 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856f at 0xae in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createJsonStreamerEntity
05-29 04:04:11.400 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856d at 0xb0 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createJsonStreamerEntity
05-29 04:04:11.400 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856c at 0xb2 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createJsonStreamerEntity
05-29 04:04:11.400 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xe712 at 0x04 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.404 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856e at 0x8d in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.404 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856f at 0x97 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.404 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856e at 0x9b in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.404 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856d at 0x9f in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.404 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856b at 0xd1 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.404 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8569 at 0xd5 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.404 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856a at 0xd9 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.404 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856b at 0x11b in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.404 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8569 at 0x11f in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.408 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x856a at 0x123 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.createMultipartEntity
05-29 04:04:11.408 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xf69b at 0xf9 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.getParamsList
05-29 04:04:11.408 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xf69b at 0x29 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.getParamsList
05-29 04:04:11.408 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xe6d9 at 0x14 in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.put
05-29 04:04:11.408 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xe6d9 at 0x1d in Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;.put
05-29 04:04:11.412 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 278K, 11% free 3279K/3664K, paused 1ms, total 2ms
05-29 04:04:11.416 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 62K, 10% free 3428K/3804K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
05-29 04:04:11.416 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 4.526MB for 1127532-byte allocation
05-29 04:04:11.420 5843-5852/com.example.administrator.login D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 8% free 4528K/4908K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
05-29 04:04:11.428 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Lcz/msebera/android/httpclient/Header;)
05-29 04:04:11.428 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY: returning Ljava/lang/Object; (cl=0x0), declared [Ljava/lang/Object; (cl=0x0)
05-29 04:04:11.428 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x11 at 0x0002
05-29 04:04:11.428 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler;.getRequestHeaders ()[Lcz/msebera/android/httpclient/Header;
05-29 04:04:11.428 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: Verifier rejected class Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
05-29 04:04:11.428 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-29 04:04:11.428 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cabb20)
05-29 04:04:11.428 5843-5843/com.example.administrator.login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.administrator.login, PID: 5843
                                                                               java.lang.VerifyError: com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler
                                                                                   at com.example.administrator.login.activity.LoginActivity.checkLogin(LoginActivity.java:146)
                                                                                   at com.example.administrator.login.activity.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:109)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using below code for login. It's working in Lollipop 5.0,5.1,6.0
But in 4.4,4.2 am getting the above mentioned error. What should I do? Techgeeks please help me.

```
onHttpRequest.post("login", requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        hideDialog();
        try {

            String s=new String(responseBody);
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(s);
            boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

            // Check for error node in json
            if (!error) {
                // user successfully logged in
                // Create login session

                // Now store the user in SQLite


                JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                String name = user.getString("name");
                String email = user.getString("email");

                // Starting a session
                userSessionManager.createUserLoginSession(name,
                        email);

                // Launch main activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                        SplashActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("email",email);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                // Error in login. Get the error message
                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // JSON error
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        hideDialog();
        // When Http response code is '404'
        if(statusCode == 404){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // When Http response code is '500'
        else if(statusCode == 500){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // When Http response code other than 404, 500
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
});
```